# Error message appeared when i want to add foxy proxy extension to Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

i want to add foxy proxy extension to chrome browser but when i click the "+ free" button it goes like "checking..." and then says:"an error has occurred, There was a problem adding the item to Chrome. Please refresh the page and try again." I do reload and try again but it's just the same thing.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More and more Internet connections are being filtered, from public **Wi-Fi** and workplace connection filtering to **ISP** and country-level censorship.

**to solve this problem you should:**

Connect to a [virtual private network](http://www.howtogeek.com/133680/htg-explains-what-is-a-vpn/) and all traffic coming from your computer will be redirected over that VPN. In other words, if you’re connected to a VPN located in USA, all your network traffic will be redirected to USA before it emerges. Replies will be send to the server in USA, which will forward them back to you. This all happens over an encrypted connection. All your ISP, network operator, or even your country’s government can see is that you’re making an encrypted VPN connection and sending data over the connection. If they want to block you, they’d have to block VPN connections. Free VPNs are available, but a solid, fast VPN will cost you money — either to rent from a VPN provider or to pay for hosting so you can set up your own VPN.